# Extract url values from URL pattern in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating MVC application which contain one view and its controller. I want to apply different theme for two different application on the same view.
For this I mapped the URL in web.config as below:

```
<add url="~/WebApplication" mappedUrl="~/Home/" />
<add url="~/XEApplication" mappedUrl="~/Home/" />
```

When i launch any of the url, it will hit HomeController.

Now my question is that when I launch the any given above url 
For ex:- "http://localhost:61691/WebApplication"
I want to get the application name like WebApplication or  XEApplication  in cshtml file. For this output:-WebApplication

For this I have tried following code in cshtml

```
var applicationName = Request.Url.LocalPath;
```

I am getting controller name using above code but i want the name of the application like WebApplication or  XEApplication in variable applicationName.

Please let me know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code,

```
Request.ApplicationPath
```

Comment: Same output as previous one.

Answer (score 0):

For that please configure your Url Routing to have your "applicationcode" Parameter
Please have a look in below code,

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{applicationcode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { applicationcode = "WebApplication", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

To Get your application code, 
Please try

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = this.RouteData.Values["applicationcode"];
        return View();
    }
```

Let me know if this is works for you.

Comment: This is the working in case when I launched the url :- http://localhost:61691/WebApplication but when I use http://localhost:61691/XeApplication, in this case the output as controller name but my expectation as XeApplication. Please let me know how to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured routing properly?

Could you please send your routing config and routdata snippet?

Please check my output at https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1Tbl.png

Regards
Ashish Sapkale

Comment: thanks for your reply but you have done the same  in controller. I am trying to get value in _viewstart.cshtml. I am using the code there :- var b = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["applicationcode"]; but i am not getting value there. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

For same routing config,

You can get values in Global.asax, Begin_Request event using below code,

```
HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(currentContext);
        string applicationcode = Convert.ToString(routeData.Values["applicationcode"]);
```

You can also try,

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Trim('/')
```

Comment: Same output as previous one. Thanks for your reply.